# How to match values in a DataFrame with some conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes and I haven't been able to accomplish this simple task, I want to match 2 columns and if that condition is True then append the value in the respective row. Something like this.

```
      0        1        weight
0     Pablo    Frida       2
1     Pablo     Andy       1
2     Pablo  Vincent       1
3    Claude  Georgia       3
4    Claude     Andy       1
5   Georgia     Andy       1
6      Andy    Frida       1
7      Andy     Joan       1
8      Andy      Lee       1
9   Vincent    Frida       2
10     Joan      Lee       3 

         0       1      2    weight
0      Andy   Claude   0     0.0
1      Andy    Frida  20     0.0
2      Andy  Georgia -10     0.0
3      Andy     Joan  30     0.0
4      Andy      Lee -10     0.0
..
..
17    Frida  Vincent  60     0.0
18  Georgia     Joan   0     0.0
```

And the expected result would be something like this:

```
        0       1      2    weight
0      Andy   Claude   0     1
1      Andy    Frida  20     1
2      Andy  Georgia -10     1
3      Andy     Joan  30     1
4      Andy      Lee -10     1
..
..
17    Frida  Vincent  60     2
18  Georgia     Joan   0     0.0
```

So the problem I am facing is that the columns could be in different order i.e. it is a set of names. 
The first DataFrame has a dimension of (11,3)
The second DataFrame has a dimension of (19,4)

How can I deal with this problem?? I am trying something like this:

```
for i in len(df2):
    if df1[0][i] == df2[0][i] or df1[0][i] == df2[1][i] and df1[1][i] == df2[0][i]  or df1[0][i] == df2[0][i]:
        df2['weight'][i] = df1['weight'][i]
```

Comment: Post your code attempt.

Comment: start with this: `pandas.merge(df1, df2, on=[0, 1], how='outer')`

Comment: @PaulH thanks I appreciate it, and it is the problem I am facing cuz after merging this way I would have duplicate rows, because the names maybe in different columns so this approach will not work for a larger data set, another idea to deal with these problem????

Comment: Paul's only giving you an guess on your comment saying matching 2 columns; but it's not clear what columns you are trying to match, and you should give your condition as well. `outer merge` is a close resemblance of `sql and`, you will get duplicates. could you post your condition as well, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the columns -

```
df1.iloc[:, :2] = np.sort(df1.iloc[:, :2], axis=1)
df2.iloc[:, :2] = np.sort(df2.iloc[:, :2], axis=1)
```

Now, perform a inner `merge` -

```
df2 = df2.drop('weight', 1).merge(df1, on=['0', '1'])
df2.head()

      0        1   2  weight
0  Andy   Claude   0       1
1  Andy    Frida  20       1
2  Andy  Georgia -10       1
3  Andy     Joan  30       1
4  Andy      Lee -10       1
```

Comment: Thanks mate, the trick was in sorting the columns!!! never thought on it, I was trying to create sets to make a single comparison.

Comment: @GuillermoIzquierdo Yeah, sometimes the most obvious choice is the one you didn't consider. Happy coding!